# Uninstall pdfforge requires allowing an unknown program to run

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall pdfforge Toolbar. I have inadvertently installed it alongside PDFCreator.

I go to Control Panel -> Unisntall Program. But it asks me to allow an unknown program to run. I can tell little about that program. As per the image below (in Spanish), it is an

> Unidentified Editor
>
> Update
>
> 1.1.2
>
> Spigot, Inc.

So, to uninstall a program from Spigot, I have to allow another program from Spigot. I was wary about doing that.
I cannot know what is the executable, as I cannot switch apps at that point.

What is the recommended course of action?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NOOOOPE.

Spigot Inc. is known for unwanted stuff.

Therefore, look into adware removal techniques and / or use an uninstaller that does thorough checks (in the registry and files). (I use IObit Uninstaller)

On a general term, Window's Uninstall program found in Control Panel just launches the program's uninstaller. That's it.

Please do a thorough check for left over files before declaring it gone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. IObit has even a portable version. I will make an image of the partition, and try it. I was fully aware of the rest of your comments.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you close the uninstaller (don't follow the steps to uninstall, just close the whole thing) you can proceed straight to the scanning part. (It scans in the registry and files)

Comment: Could you please be more specific/comprehensive as to the steps for a "thorough check"?

Comment: Thorough check is vague; it can range from running more scan on other programs or antivirus softwares, manually searching for the file or its relatives (in this case, pdfforge or "spigot inc")